# Manipulating a webpage by its source

Tags: c#, html

I have googled this with a couple of differing terms and I could not find my solution. What I want to do is to manipulate a webpage by editing its source, for example removing a part from the code maybe a div or so. I know how to get the source of a webpage and know how to change the code but I have no idea how to manipulate the page instantly, by for example removing an element.

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you not just make the page an ASP page? This way you have a lot more control - or is this running a standard c# winforms/wpf app that you want to edit the page from?

Comment: I haven't decided which kind of application would be best for it, but as long as it is C# I think I could handle this. What's the difference of an ASP page? Could you explain how I have more control over an ASP page and how this would work?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? Maybe provide some sample code. The better you explain what you want, the better others can answer.

Comment: Please explain what you want to edit and for who. Do you want to edit the content of certain pages, then take a look at a CMS. If you want to edit the page's markup for everyone to see (i.e. your site's template(s)), use a CMS which allows you to do so. If you want to update a portion of a page when a client or the server initiates an action, take a look at AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to manipulate client code (HTML) what you need is **Ajax**.

  You can use **JQuery** javascript library to manipulate html of a page adding, editing and removing html tags, scripts, etc.

  [Here](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/jquery-ajax-examples-by-calling-aspnet.html) you can find a decent tutorial as a start point.
- If you want to manipulate server code (C# codebehind) what you need is creating a web project in visual studio (ASP.NET Web Application)

**EDIT**: As commented by **@CSharpened** both solutions are not mutual exclusive. You can have an ASP.NET Web application that uses Ajax to manipulate UI. In fact lot of people does that.

Comment: Yeah, though I might point out that this is all client-side, do you want to do it server-side?

Comment: It should be pointed out that AJAX can also be used in web applications to allow client side and server side manipulation in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using AJAX. You can use either javascript or jquery coupled with html, asp.net and C# to achieve the results you are after.

For simple editing like removing divs or collapsing menus etc simple Javascript or jquery will suffice. However changing the coding of the page requires you to use AJAX or similar.